# How to Redirect a URL using Application Gateway with Query included and Path excluded

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I am not able to successfully redirect a URL with query to another target external URL.

eg:-
Request URL:- http://example123.com/xxx/yy?path=com
Target URL:- http://example456.com/zzz/yy

Condition:-
I need to include the query string from the Request URL but not the Path.

I have tried using the path-based routing rule on the App GateWay with below configuration

[Redirect rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp77z.png)

But after hitting save its going back to a state like this:

[Rule after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r8hv.png)

Can anyone please find us a solution ??

Answer (score 0):

According to   [configuration-request-routing-rules (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/configuration-request-routing-rules.md#rule-type)  ,
Path based rule may not send path to query and only applies it to path of url.

> When you create a rule, you choose between [basic and path-based](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/application-gateway-components.md#request-routing-rules).
>
> - Choose **basic** if you want to forward all requests on the associated    listener (for example, blog.contoso.com/*) to a single back-end pool.
> - Choose **path-based** if you want to route requests from specific URL    paths to specific back-end pools. The path pattern is applied only to
>   the path of the URL, not to its query parameters.

Also see [external-site  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-request-routing-rules#external-site)

Please check if you can try the [rewriting URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url#url-path-and-query-string) path instead of redirecting which  refers to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-url-portal) for implementation.